# Web Services - default value ignores or clears a field?

Tags: web-services, asp.net-web-api

We're developing a web service based on .NET webApi that will allow customers to create and update objects. When the model is handed to our controller, how do we differentiate between fields that are null/blank/0 because the caller wanted them set to null/blank/0, or fields that are null/blank/0 because that's the default used by parameter binding when the caller had no intentions of setting a value for that field? Is there a standard for dealing with this?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just check the ModelState property on your controller. If a WebAPI action is invoked and the ModelState is valid, then it should mean that all the parameters were successfully bound from the URI or deserialized from the request body.

There's one caveat - this is only true for WebAPI's default parameter bindings. If you register your own custom parameter binding that binds the parameter differently, then all bets are off.

Now as far as properties and fields of parameters go, it's up to the formatter to decide how to handle those. Deserializers have two options when they encounter a member that's missing. They can either throw, or they can populate the member with 0/blank/null. You can ask the formatter to add a model state error when the property is missing by marking the property as [Required] or by using [DataMember(IsRequired=true)] if you're using the data contract model.